# Formatting issues, certain indices returning NoneType?

Tags: python

So my program essentially takes a bunch of exam dates from a csv file, then stores them in a list. I then run my function findSchedule with the values of the csv file as arguments. The findSchedule returns a value just fine, but when I try to format it, on certain indices, it returns a "NoneType" value. Here is my code:

```
import csv

def findSchedule(days,time,cr,period):          
    if days == "TR":
        if time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")     
        elif time == "12:30" or time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "3:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "6:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:30":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "5":
            return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
    elif days == "MWF":
        if time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "3:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "6:30" or time == "8:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM" and time == "8:00":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "4:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "3:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
        elif time == "3:00":
            return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
        elif time == "11:00" and cr == "5":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
    elif days == "MW":
        if time == "8:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "9:00":
            return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "3:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "1":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 7:25 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "2":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 8:20 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "3":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 9:30 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "4":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 10:15 pm")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "5":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")

    elif days == "R":
        if time == "6:30" and period == "PM":
            return("Thursday, December 15, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
    elif days == "WF":
        if time == "8:00" and (cr == "2" or cr == "5"):
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("No class found")
        elif time == "8:00" and cr == "4":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            if period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "9:30":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "12:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Classs not found")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "3:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "3:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "4:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "2":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "4":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "3:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
    elif days == "M":
        if time == "6:30":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 7:25 pm")
    elif days == "T":
        if time == "6:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
    else:
        if (cr == "4" or cr == "2") and time == "12:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 1:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "3:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 10:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "3:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "5" and time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "5" and time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:30":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 10:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "4:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")   
        else:
            return("Class final not found, please try again")

csvCourses = []
csvExamTime = []
examTime = []
Test = []

with open("final_exam_schedule.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ",")
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        csvCourses.append(row)

for i in range(len(csvCourses)):
    csvExamTime.append(csvCourses[i][5])
    examTime.append(findSchedule(csvCourses[i][4],csvCourses[i][1],csvCourses[i][3],csvCourses[i][2]))

for i in range(len(csvCourses)):
    if examTime[i] == csvExamTime[i]:
        Test.append("Pass")
    else:
        Test.append("False")


print("{0:5}{1:40}{2:60}{3:40}".format("#","Correct Date","Your Date","Test"))
print("~"*110)
for i in range(len(csvCourses)):
    print("{0!s:5}{1!s:40}{2!s:60}{3!s:40}".format(int(csvCourses[i][0])-1,csvCourses[i][5],examTime[i],Test[i]))
```

I know the if/else statements are messy in my function (since I've had to tweak it several times for my project), but rest assured it returns a value. When I print one of the bad indices that give me a "NoneType" in the formatting, calling the findSchedule function on it, it gives me the correct value. So why is this value not appearing when I try to format it?

Comment: A `dictionary` would solve your problems ! Take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file

Comment: Also this code is neither robust nor maintainable. You should consider re-writing your code in a more functional form - then it would be much easier for you to debug and develop it. What if we solve this issue now and another one come up later !

Comment: I understand it isn't very robust haha, my CS teacher wanted us to use if/else statements to assign values, and there is alot of different dates and such. Also, whenever I use the dictionary method, it seems that my indices go out of order, instead of naturally 1,2,3,4 etc. Why is this?

Comment: `dictionaries` in python are by default **unordered** - so to access certain values you will have to use the `keys()`. Now even sorting them wouldn't have meaning as it will be unstable. If you want to use a sorted dictionary  which at the same time will be stable use OrderedDict:   https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Ok, and can you explain why my original method of using a list does not work?