# Saving and loading dictionary into python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the code below to save a dictionary to csv in python. How can I load this back in?

There are a few answers on here, but none seem to be working

```
file='Location'
with open(file, 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, mydic.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(mydic)
```

Comment: *What* answers did you try and *how* don't they seem to be working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dictionary from a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to save a `dictionary` as `json` file.

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(mydic, fp)
```

To load the `json` file:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as fp:
    mydic = json.load(fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a way to deal with saving and loading dictionary is to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Saving:

```
import pickle
some_file = open("file", "wb")
my_dictionary = {"aa":"aa"}
pickle.dump(my_dictionary, some_file)
some_file.close()
```

Reading back:

```
import pickle
some_file = open("file", "r")
my_dictionary = pickle.load(some_file)
```

Please remember that using `pickle` is not safe while dealing with data received from the untrusted source.

Comment: Define "correct". For flat dictionaries and simple values, a CSV will do fine as well.

Comment: It's simple, efficient and universal. It's marshalling by python. It doesn't require to jump between different data types (doesn't require additional abstraction layer).

Comment: True. It also has the potential to break between different Python versions, and it's not human readable, sooo…

Comment: How is it not human readable? How is saying "just dump that object into a file" not readable? :) Different python versions shouldn't even be a problem. It's never recommended to just swap between versions. Version migration is a process.

Comment: The file that is written is not human readable. The code that writes it is, the resulting file is not. That may or may not be a problem. You also don't know whether this file is supposed to be interchangeable with different systems and/or versions. – Pickling is an entirely cromulent thing to do, no doubt. But you can't universally claim that it's "correct" when it has a number of caveats you need to be aware of.

Comment: Ok, I have changed `correct` to `a` :) I guess there is no point to continue this discussion.