# Way to extract columns from a CSV and place them into a dictionary

Tags: csv, dictionary

So basically I'm at a wall with an assignment and it's beginning to really frustrate me. Essentially I have a CSV file and my goal is to count how an the amount of times a string is called. So like column 1 would have a string and column 2 would have a integer connected to it. I ultimately need this to be formatted into a dictionary. Where I am stuck is how the heck do I do this without using imported libraries. I am only allowed to iterate through the file using for loops. Would my best bet be indexing each line and creating that into a string and count how many times that string is called? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dictionary from a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to you any library (and assuming you are using python) you can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), like this:

```
with open("data.csv") as file:
    csv_as_dict = {line[0]: line[1] for line in file.readlines()}
```

Note: The question is possibly a duplicate of [Creating a dictionary from a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file#6740968).