# Creating a dict from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a `csv file` which looks like this

```
   header1   header2   header3
1  value1    value2    value3
2  value4    value5    
3            value6    value7
```

And I would like to make a dict which will look like this:

```py
{header1:[value1, value4],
header2:[value2, value5, value6],
header3:[value3, value7]

}
```

I already tried

```py
records = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in records:
         print(row)
```

But It takes first column values as keys in `dict`
what could I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a dictionary from a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

Comment: Unfortunately, the answers in the nominated duplicate all seem to replace any previous value, not build lists of values for each key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one quick and I hope obvious way.

```py
from csv import DictReader
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
records = DictReader(f)
for row in records:
     for key in row:
         result[key].append(row[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Your CSV file name")
dict1 = df.to_dict('list')
print(dict1)
```

Comment: If you (plan to) use Pandas anyway, this is terrific. If not, it's huge overkill.

Comment: The person who posted the question did not mention relevant info actually. Also, it's not too unfair to assume that pandas would be involved while dealing with CSVs right?

Comment: Why do you think Pandas is required for CSV files? If you want to do calculations or analytics then Pandas is a great tool; but again, if not, it's a massive package which you will only use a tiny part of.

Comment: I didn't say required. I just meant to say that it shouldn't directly be ruled out. Lots of data scientists often export query results to CSVs and perform analytics. The person asking this question didn't specify his intention so I posted an answer with pandas as well.

Comment: Right, and you didn't explain when it would be a good idea, so I added a comment to hopefully clarify that. It would be silly for them to go and install Pandas just for this.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks. I'm just getting started on SO so am still figuring out how much detail is too much.

Answer (score 0):

use `pandas dataframe` to read csv and convert to `dict`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep=',')
df.to_dict('list')
```

It gives the below output.

```
{
'header1': ['value1', 'value4', nan],
 'header2': ['value2', 'value5    ', 'value6'],
 'header3': ['value3', nan, 'value7']
}
```