# Create dictionary from txt file - Debug

Tags: python, file, dictionary

```
name,score #an example
a,1,
s,2,
d,3,
f,4,
g,5,
h,6,
j,7,
k,8,
l,9,
q,10,
```

This is my file. I want to make this into a dictionary (a:1,s:2...)

```
number_of_lines = len(open("scores.txt").readlines(  ))
d = {}
with open("scores.txt") as f:
   for line in range(number_of_lines-1):   #-1 removes the last line which is only \n
     (key, value) = line.split(",")
     d[key] = value
print(d)
```

I keep getting the error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' don't know why.

Can you debug this?

Thank in advance,

Comment: `range(number_of_lines-1)` will give you ints from 0 to number_of_lines -1, so line will be an int and on each loop will increse. so, `0, 1, 2, 3` etc, so you cant split an int. Do you mean to do `(key, value) = f.readline().split(",")` but i dont see why you care about the length of the file

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thanks for responding. Then length is an issue because then I get the error expecting only 2, because there is another line at the end of the file with only \n

Comment: @Daniel That has to do with your logic in looping over the lines. You can safely do `if len(line.strip()) == 0: continue` assuming you actually put the line itself in the variable `line`. See my code below, third example. Should explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) returns numbers, not the actual lines. Since you store the output of `range` into `lines` you won't be able to do `line.split()` as `line`is not the actual line, but the value from `range()`. Instead, do something like this:

```
d = {}
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split(",")
        d[key] = value
print(d)
```

If you need the index of the line you're on (which you never used, so I don't know if you do), you can use the `enumerate` function.

```
d = {}
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        key, value = line.split(",")
        d[key] = value
print(d)
```

Mentioned in the comments, there's issues with length of the file etc. But that can be safely checked in the for loop:

```
d = {}
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        if len(line.strip()) <= 0: continue
        elif index == 0: continue # Skip the header or use the CSV lib
        key, value = line.split(",")
        d[key] = value
print(d)
```

To better understand this, you can lab with the `range` function (if you don't like to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)) on a more standalone basis by doing:

```
for line in range(0, 10):
    print(type(line), line)
```

Hopefully this solves your issue but also teaches what the range function does.

Lastly, consider using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv
with open('scores.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row['name'], row['score'])
```

Pro's: handles empty lines, sorts everything in to a dictionary for you, skips the headers (or more accurately, puts them in as the key in the dict per row) and lastly, handles a lot of CSV "magic" for you (like special delimiters, quote chars etc)

You can use the csv lib to [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6740968/929999) create the final result that you're after altho it's a bit slow, you'd probably better off reading and working with the data line by line unless it's for database purposes like this:

```
import csv
with open('scores.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    d = {row['name']:row['score'] for row in reader}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The first example get the error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) which is why I chose range, I will look at the others

Comment: @Daniel Check the third example, as it explains that particular issue. It has to do with the fact that you're not checking if the line is empty or not. I also added a "skip the first (0) line" as it's a CSV header item and you probably don't want that in your dict. But ultimately, just use the `csv` library, it takes care of these things for you.

Comment: I get the same for the second one

Comment: The last one gives TypeError: 'delimiter' is an invalid keyword argument for open()

Comment: @Daniel Yepp, sorry, meant to put that on the `csv.reader` object as it's a csv property not a file property. Fixed the type-o. That's what you get for being to fast when writing it off : ) But the example is taken from the documentation so the correct information was there all along :)

Comment: @Daniel glad it was of use. I added a bonus slightly stolen inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file) as I didn't find it until I was writing this comment. But that would give you your final result I hope.

Comment: It's good to learn the essence of range and all of its uses and qualities

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas for this

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_csv('scores.txt').set_index('name')['score'].to_dict()
```

This works well with comma separated files, and is faster

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dict comprehension:

```
data = """
a,1,
s,2,
d,3,
f,4,
g,5,
h,6,
j,7,
k,8,
l,9,
q,10,
"""

dct = {key: value for line in data.split("\n") if line for key, value, *_ in [line.split(",")]}
print(dct)
# {'a': '1', 's': '2', 'd': '3', 'f': '4', 'g': '5', 'h': '6', 'j': '7', 'k': '8', 'l': '9', 'q': '10'}
```

---

Or - with your file (considering the header, that is):

```
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    dct = {key: value 
           for line in data.split("\n")[1:] if line 
           for key, value, *_ in [line.split(",")]}
```

Comment: Friendly reminder to the OP, don't miss the detail that Jan ignored `name,score #an example` at the start of your file - aka, don't forget to manipulate the data into the above example.

Comment: @Torxed: Thanks for spotting that out. I updated the `file` section.