# making python dictionary from excel table

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary from an Excel file.

Excel sheet (2r: nearly 3000 columns) looks like this:

[image]

And I want my outcome to look like this:

```
dictionary ={ 
              "aa": "male", 
              "ab": "female",
              ...,
              "name_N": "gender_N"
              }
```

I wrote my code as follows, however, it does not work.

```
import csv

dictionary = {}
with open('genderword_sk2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for row in reader:
    dictionary[row['name']] = row['gender']
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: Is this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file) what you are looking for?

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is an error message I've got

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-e4877a19e73b> in <module>
      5     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
      6     for row in reader:
----> 7         dictionary[row['name']] = row['gender']

KeyError: 'name'

Comment: Error traceback should be part of question. Did you read the error message? Did you try to debug? E.g., print the `row` variable before it crashes?

Comment: Also, you appear to be closing the file before you read it

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

dictionary = {}

with open('genderword_sk2.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(csvreader)

    for row in csvreader:
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]

print(dictionary)
```

This was the content of my csv:

```
name,gender
Anne,female
Tom,male
```

And the result was:

```
{'Anne': 'female', 'Tom': 'male'}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('genderword_sk2.csv')

dictionary = {df['name'].iloc[i] : df['gender'].iloc[i] for i in df.index}
```