# Compare 2 columns in one csv file(percentages)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, percentage

I am a novice doing a course in python. My task is the following. I have a csv file (cameraData) containing several columns that looks like this:

```
IDnumber;Speedlimit;Speed;Date;Time
14075010;40;55;2021-09-11;11:15:31
14075010;40;54;2021-09-11;08:09:17
14075010;40;53;2021-09-11;13:02:41
14075010;40;49;2021-09-11;13:02:55
```

I want to compare the Speedlimit column with the Speed column. The idea is that the user can input a percentage and the program returns a list with the speeds that are x % over the speed limit. I am not allowed to use pandas. I have tried using dictreader and nested for loops to iterate through the 2 columns. I cant really figure out how to do it without pandas. I have also though about using zip() but I think it might be a bit of a workaround. I am unsure what is the best way to compare the columns(percentage wise). Here is my code so far:

```
import csv

#convert input to percentage decimal
percentoverspeedlimit = input("Input percentage over speed limit: ") 
percentage = float(percentoverspeedlimit) 
percentage_decimal = 1 + (variable / 100)

#create new function and empty dict
def speedlimitplus(camera_data):
    overspeedlimit={}
    
#open file
    with open(camera_data, 'r') as p:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader (p, delimiter = ';')
            for row in csv_reader:
                overspeedlimit[row['Speedlimit']] = overspeedlimit.get(row['Speedlimit'], 0) + 1
                
    return overspeedlimit

#use function
camera_data = speedlimitplus('cameraData.csv')

print(overspeedlimit)
```

I have been struggling to find example code that isn´t pandas. Resources, example code or hints/tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with this line:

```py
overspeedlimit[row['Speedlimit']] = overspeedlimit.get(row['Speedlimit'], 0) + 1
```

To solve this problem, you can indeed use `csv.DictReader` to parse the data into an iterable of dictionaries containing the data for each row. In your loop instead of the above you can directly access the `Speedlimit` and the `Speed`, compare them against the user inputted percentage and print when neccessary:

```py
import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    percentage = float(input(r"% over speed limit to filter by: "))
    with open("./cameraData.csv", "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            if (float(row["Speed"]) - float(row["Speedlimit"])) / float(row["Speedlimit"]) * 100 > percentage:
                # do something to row dictionary here before printing?
                print(row)
```

Which gives:

```
% over speed limit to filter by: 30
{'IDnumber': '14075010', 'Speedlimit': '40', 'Speed': '55', 'Date': '2021-09-11', 'Time': '11:15:31'}
{'IDnumber': '14075010', 'Speedlimit': '40', 'Speed': '54', 'Date': '2021-09-11', 'Time': '08:09:17'}
{'IDnumber': '14075010', 'Speedlimit': '40', 'Speed': '53', 'Date': '2021-09-11', 'Time': '13:02:41'}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the last alternative using csv.dictreader. It seems that print(row) prints all rows irregardless of the if statement. Am I missing something? It seems your calculation does not result in the rows where speed is x% greater than the speed limit. I tried adding the following but it still doesnt print the correct rows.   ```
                        faktor = (percentage/100)+1
                        if float(row['Hastighet'])*faktor > float(row['Gällande Hastighet']): 
                        print(row)
                        ```

Comment: @Zrocks2000, sorry you are correct, I've updated the calculation to find the correct percentage. Should work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a fucntion that will get user input percentage and list that contains tuples of "Speed Limit" and "Speed", compare with input and print;

```
def compare(input_percentage, data_list):
    for i in data_list:
        percentage = (i[1]-i[0]/i[1])*100
        if percentage > input_percentage:
            print(f"Over Speed Percentage is higher than input percentage: {i}")
        else:
            pass
```

You can construct this function to your need. You can also generate dictionary when importing csv and use that too. To create dictionary reading csv file check this post : [Creating a dictionary from a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file)

If you pass dictionary to function you can also create new key and value regarding your comparison.

Function that gets user input and dictionary:

```
dictionary_list = [{"IDnumber: 14075010,"
                    "Speedlimit": 40,
                    "Speed": 55,
                    "Date": "2021-09-11",
                    "Time": "11:15:31"
                   ]

def compare(input_percentage, dictionary_list):
    for item  in dictionary_list:
        percentage = (item["Speedlimit"] - item["Speed"]) / item["Speed"] * 100
        if percentage > input_percentage:
            print(f"ID number: {item['IDnumber']} is over input percentage")
        else:
            pass
```